# I dont get why is the correct answer the one circled in green and not the above one, what is the use of the \\ ( backslash) and \\\?

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

[image]

I don't get why is the correct answer the one circled in green and not the above one, what is the use of the \\ ( backslash) and \\\ ?

Comment: Do you see `///` anywhere?

Comment: Because that's how the backslash works in string literals. Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation), or any JS intro or tutorial, or search on Stack Overflow for "javascript escape backslash".

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses backslashes in strings to escape.
If you're trying to use `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\` you will need to add another backslash before each one, and before each quotation mark.

```js
console.log("The file located at \"C:\\\\Desktop\""); //correct
console.log("The file located at \"C:\\Desktop"); // wrong

//console.log("The file located at "C:\\\Desktop\""); gives error
```

Answer (score -1):

Because we can't directly show '\' and ' " ' in a string as these characters have other specific meaning like: backslash, newline etc and known as escape characters. We need to escape them using '\' (a backslash). For example if we want to show:

`abc\def\\ghi` in a string then it should be written as:

```
abc\\def\\\\ghi
```

otherwise it will print `abcdef\ghi`. We can't write single ' " ' in string it will give error to print this it should be written as: ' \" '.

```js
console.log("abc\def\\ghi");//wrong
console.log("abc\\def\\\\ghi");//correct
```

For more information visit [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp).

Answer (score -1):

Just to get on the same page: / is a forward slash, \ is a backslash.

Backslashes must be escaped (with a backslash) so they aren't mistaken as escape-characters for the character following them.